# Does using a global constants defined by framework within class methods breaks the Dependency Injection principle?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, dependency-inversion

With constants coming from the framework you are using. i.e, `ABSPATH` in WordPress.

How badly will it break the Dependency Injection principle if I do not add the value of that constant as a dependency in `constructor` function of the class, and just use it directly inside method?

Say, strictly DI speaking, you need to do something like:

```
class Foo {

    private $abspath;

    public function __construct(string $abspath) {
         $this->abspath = $abspath
    }

    public function get_assets_dir() {
        return $this->abspath . '/assets/';
    }

}

$foo = new Foo(ABSPATH);
$foo->get_assets_dir();
```

but instead something like?

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct() {
         //nothing here.
    }

    public function get_assets_dir() {
        return ABSPATH . '/assets/';
    }

}
```

Do I really still have to do it if it will always be defined since it sits on top of a framework that defines it by default?

Comment: Are you expecting to use the abspath where it is not the wordpress one? If you are sure it is always wordpress (e.g. even in unit tests, or e.g. if you won't call this in unit tests), you don't need DI at all.

Comment: @SOFe interesting, do you reckon I only need DI for unit testing?

Comment: Not sure, but performing DI to an extreme is not going to be beneficial if you (can be confident that) never need some other value at its place.

Comment: It really depends on your case. In your example, it is not very clear what `Foo` is supposed to do. If it is simply a class that returns the assets directory... well, why do you even need such a class? Isn't `get_assets_dir` good enough as a static method, if it's gonna return a constant? If it is gonna return something different, is it because you wanted a dynamic paths provider? Then this boils down to whether you needed the `Foo` class to begin with. It appears that it is the `Foo` class rather than the `abspath` property that is performing DI.

Comment: @SOFe ah gotcha

Comment: There is no such thing as "dependency injection principle". Did you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle? Also the issue with constants is the same as with global variables - they both constitute global state (only one is mutable and other - immutable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, yes. (Although it's called the "Dependency Inversion Principle", not "Dependency Injection" principle. The "Dependency Injection Pattern" it's a subpattern of the "Inversion of Control" principle; related but not the same. Read more about this [here](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

`ABSPATH` is dependency for your `Foo` class, it is defined outside by different part of the application. If your class needs that value, and aims to be completely decoupled from the "framework", you should inject it (disregarding that the constant belongs to the global state, if you are really encapsulating your class, it doesn't need to be aware of that).

Realistically, if your class is solely for use in Wordpress (and it looks that way), I wouldn't worry too much. You are already coupled to your "framework" anyway.